# Java: Превратить csv файлы с разными колонками в коллекции объектов

Tags: java, парсер, csv, pojo

У меня есть 4 csv файла. Каждый из них хранит в себе разные данные и разные название колонок (схемы).
Мне нужно распарсить эти файлы и превратить их в  4 List-а, которые хранят объекты разных видов (в зависимости от файла и его схемы, например Obj1, Obj2, Obj3. То есть , я бы хотела создать такой метод, в который я передаю класс объекта, который я хочу создать и сам файл. А этот метод возвратит мне лист с этими обьектами.

Какой самый лучший способ сделать это в Java, наиболее оптимально?  Может, есть какие-либо специальные библиотеки, которые позволяют это сделать?

Comment: содержат ли csv файлы заголовки колонок? какие типы данных хранятся и в каких типах данных нужно представить ? (например, считать строками все колонки будет намного проще, но ведь типизация может потребоваться для дальнейшей обработки данных)

Comment: @DaysLikeThis спасибо за ответ! типы данных - разные, в основном, стринг и дабл.  Заголовки колонок тоже содержатся в файле!

Comment: библиотеки предлагались в этом (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853357/how-to-parse-a-delimited-flat-file-to-a-pojo) ответе. Можно попробовать сделать свою реализацию, метод получает на вход csv файл и объект, в который нужно считать, с помощью Java Reflection можно инициализировать необходимый класс и заполнить его поля (например, по порядку - поле 1 = 1 токен из csv файла, поле 2 = 2 токен и т.д, либо в классе сделать имена переменных такими же как названия колонок в csv файле и задавать соответствующие значения. В любом случае, java reflection поможет определить тип данных

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/), обратите внимание на  `com.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy` или его подклассы для автоматического маппинга по заголовкам колонок.